# regex js: Replace character by unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm writing a jQuery Plug-In to replace spaces or non-spaces before `!` or `?` by a `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE` as it's common in french. The thing is I don't manage to replace something by a unicode character.

```js
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).text(text.replace(/.\?/g, '\u202F\?'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply; random text ! It has roots in a piece. of classical Latin literature from 45 BC?</p>
```

Comment: Well, the code does not seem to work at all. Note that you can also replace with `&#8239;` entity. `.replace(/.\?/g, '&#8239;?')`

Comment: I my example, I would like to add narrow no-break space between the C and the ? on the last sentence.

Comment: Then try `.replace(/.(?=\?)/g, '$&&#8239;')`

Comment: It display the &#8239; in letter

Comment: You mean by set the meta charset in UTF-8 ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, don't assign text to html.

Comment: @Qwertiy - I do not :) I just meant that if the value is assigned to the `document.body.innerHTML`, it will show as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the text replacement only,

```
    text.replace(/[ \u202F]*([!\?])/g, "\u202F$1")
```

converts zero or more space or  narrow non break space characters in `text`, followed by '!' or '?', into a single narrow non break space character followed by the '!' or '?' character matched (tested in Firefox and IE).

```
[ \u202F]
```

within the regular expression defines a character set to match spaces and includes the narrow non breaking space character itself. This could be extended to include specific additional space characters such as non breaking space (`\u00A0`), tabs, or replaced with `\s` to match *any* white space characters including line feeds.

Answer (score 0):

All spaces and non-spaces before `?` will be replaced by your `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`

```
var text = $('p').text();
$('p').text(text.replace(/\s*\?/g, '\u202F\?'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tct4e73c/1/

**Update**

Added `!`

```
var text = $('p').text();
$('p').text(text.replace(/.\s*(?=!|\?)/g, '\u202F'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tct4e73c/2/