# Why can't I replace a string that contains a unicode?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a unicode in a string using regex with JavaScript flavor. However, I am unable to replace the unicode string with the desire string.

This works as expected:

```
function replacer(match, p1) {
  return "World";
}
var newString = 'Hello9A'.replace(/[0-9A-F]{2}/g, replacer);
console.log(newString); // HelloWorld
```

This is the code that I am trying to get it to work:

```
function replacer(match, p1) {
  console.log("match: ", match);
  console.log("p1: ", p1);
  return "World";
}
var newString = 'Hello\u0B70'.replace(/\\u[0-9A-F]{4}/g, replacer);
console.log(newString);
```

My expected `newString` should be `HelloWorld`. However, I am getting `Hello୰`.

I even tested on Regex101 and that the regex is indeed capturing `\u0B70`. At the same time, I am not able to log out `match` and `p1`, which I am not sure why.

What is the correct way to replace that unicode with my desired string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex js: Replace character by unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849114/regex-js-replace-character-by-unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern

```
\\u[0-9A-F]{4}
```

will match part of a string with *literally contains* a backslash, followed by a `u`, followed by 4 hex characters. But your input string contains only 6 characters, 5 of which are "hello":

```js
console.log('Hello\u0B70');
console.log('Hello\u0B70'.length);
```

You need to match the *actual Unicode character* there:

```js
function replacer(match, p1) {
  console.log("match: ", match);
  console.log("p1: ", p1);
  return "World";
}
var newString = 'Hello\u0B70'.replace(/\u0B70/g, replacer);
console.log(newString);
```

If you wanted to match *any unicode character at all* (which translates to "any character", basically), you can use a character set, like

```
[\u0000-\uFFFF]
```

but alphabetical characters like "Hello" are Unicode too, of course, so they'll be matched as well, which isn't what you want - figure out the precise range of characters you want to match, and put that range into the character set.